# Laravel Homestead Error on vagrant up

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have an issue in my Laravel Homestead and Vagrant. I have set up everything in the correct way by reading the Laravel Homestead docs and watching some videos.

When I start the `vagrant up` command I have this issue:

```html
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available! You cu
rrently
==> default: have version '0.2.5'. The latest is version '0.2.6'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/va
grant/util/io.rb:32:in `encode': "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::Unde
finedConversionError)
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/io.rb:32:in `read_until_block'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:144:in `block in execute'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:142:in `each'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:142:in `execute'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22:in `execute'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:404:in `block in raw'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:403:in `raw'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:342:in `block in execute'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:337:in `execute'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_4_3.rb:275:in `read_bridged_i
nterfaces'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:267:in `hostonly_config'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:89:in `block in call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:82:in `each'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:82:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `ca
ll'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:18:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:84:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:19:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'

        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:160:in `ha
ndle'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `blo
ck in call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:in `lock'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `cal
l'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_para
ms.rb:30:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'

        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:68:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:214:in `action_raw'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:191:in `block in action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:in `lock'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `call'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `action'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant
-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

and nothing is done.

Comment: any solution? please guys :(
My Virtualbox work fine... i don't know where the problem.

Comment: My first thought, after searching and finding similar error message reports, is a non-ASCII character in the Windows host path or possibly the network interface (less likely). You could try moving your Vagrantfile (and other files) to a simple directory like `c:\temp` and doing `vagrant up` from there. Another idea is to enable debugging ([docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html)) and see if the resulting output gives any more detailed clues.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Homestead.yaml file for errors. Yaml doesn't like tab,use space instead when separating or adding space for the characters.Another example will trigger an error when running vagrant up

```
folders:
    -map: c:/wamp/www/laratest //wrong
      to: /var/www/Laravel
    -map: c:/wamp/www/Drupal//wrong
      to: /var/www/Drupal

folders:
   - map: c:/wamp/www/laratest//correct
      to: /var/www/Laravel
   - map: c:/wamp/www/Drupal/correct
      to: /var/www/Drupal
```